# How to sort hashable objects

Tags: python

I have a situation where I need to sort the keys of a dictionary to make sure that the list always has the same order.  I don't care what that order is.  But I need to have consistency of order.  This is causing people using a package I've written difficulties because they want to set a random seed and have consistent results for testing purposes, but even when they set a key, the order that the dictionary returns its values changes, and this ends up affecting the randomization.

I would like to do some thing like `sorted(D.keys())`.  However, in principle the keys may not be sortable.  I don't have any control over what those keys are.

I know this is solved in recent versions of python, but I don't want to restrict uses to 3.7.

More detail here: https://github.com/springer-math/Mathematics-of-Epidemics-on-Networks/issues/22#issuecomment-631219800

---

Since people think this is a bad question, here's more detail (or see the original link I provided for even more detail):

I have written an algorithm to do stochastic epidemic simulations.  For reproducibility purposes people would like to specify a seed and have it run and produce the same outcome on any machine.  The algorithm uses a networkx graph (which is built on a dictionary structure).

As part of the steps it needs to perform a weighted selection from the edges of the graph.  This requires that I put the edges into a list.  If the list is in a different order, then different outcomes occur regardless of whether the same seed is used.

So I'm left with having to find a way to make the list of edges be in a consistent order on any machine.

Comment: If consistent ordering of the dictionary is important, perhaps it should be an `OrderedDict`? Why is the ordering of the dictionary *currently* causing problems - what *are* those difficulties?

Comment: Why do the users of your package rely on dictionary ordering for test results? Dictionary equality like `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'} == {2: 'b', 1: 'a'}` should work for them in all cases.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I can't use an `OrderedDict` because it's actually coming from a networkx graph.  I could require that the user input an OrderedGraph, but I'd prefer to not do that because it's going to require an extra level of sophistication that I don't think is appropriate to the problem.

Comment: @Thomas - the algorithm needs to randomly select elements from the dictionary (roughly, a bit more nuanced than that), but which ones are selected depends on the ordering that python provides, and will vary independently of what seed the user selects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I thought I had explained those difficulties (when the order changes, the stochastic algorithm will produce different results), but I've given more details.  If you want the full info, follow the github link.

Comment: Note that the context needs to be at least summarised in this question - offsite links rot, so those links should be supplementary only. But it sounds like you might want https://stackoverflow.com/q/29275434/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - that might help, but this is within a function that a user will call, having already defined their networkx graph.  The solution is to set the environmental variable PYTHONHASHSEED, and I feel like setting that would break the code (wouldn't it make their already defined networkx graph break?).  Is there really no way to just sort a bunch of hashable objects in a consistent way?

Comment: Not if those objects don't define what being larger or smaller than each other means. Really all the hashability means is some identity property that's consistent for the life of the object and some notion of equality (see https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable); you could always successfully run a sort with `sorted(d.keys(), key=id)` but that wouldn't be stable between executions. You can't set that environment variable from your function, but the user could set it for the whole process when trying to reproduce results.

Comment: Hmm,  I assumed I'd be able to actually access a hash function (but had had no luck finding it, hence the question).

Comment: There's [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) too, but again there's no guarantee of consistent ordering by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly... the task is to consistently select the same random key from a vanilla `dict` on an old version of Python where insertion order is not preserved, while knowing nothing at all about the key type, and without setting the hash seed explicitly. I believe that's impossible in the general case, because the whole notion of object "identity" does not even exist with such restrictive assumptions.

The only thing that comes to mind is to serialize the keys in some way, and sort their serialized forms. `pickle.dumps` should work on most key types (although not everything can be pickled). But if the key type does allow sorting, it's probably more robust to simply use that instead.

```py
import pickle

try:
    sorted_keys = sorted(my_dict)
except TypeError:
    sorted_keys = sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: pickle.dumps(x, protocol=3))
```

There are some caveats though:

- The pickled representation is not the same across Python versions (see [Data stream format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocols)). That's why I'm setting `protocol=3` in the example above; this should work the same for Python 3.0 and newer, although it doesn't support as many object types as protocol 4.
- Objects can define their own pickling, so there is no guarantee that it's reproducible. In particular...
- The pickled representation of dictionaries is still dependent on the ordering of the dictionary, which depends the Python version and the hash seed. The same goes for objects, because by default these are pickled by invoking their `__dict__` method.

  If you want to get really tricky, maybe you can create a custom `Pickler` that sorts dictionaries (using `OrderedDict` for portability across Python versions) before pickling them... but in the end, it's not going to solve the full problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to preserve order one possibility is insertion order with a list of pairs. If you combine with a `OrderedDict` you will preserve order and have dictionary functions.

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict([(1,'a'),(3,'2')])
>>> d.keys()
odict_keys([1, 3])
```

Comment: I cannot make it an ordered dict.  It's coming from a networkx graph (which uses a dict for its underlying structure), which the user will have predefined.

Comment: @Joel unfortunately in that case, if you cannot hide that you're using a dict, you're stuck. A dict by definition does not guarantee any order. That's how it gets O(1) selection, insertion and deletion.

Comment: Yes, I know this.  But, say the keys were all strings, I could still sort the keys.  I'm looking for a way to consistently sort hashable objects even if the objects themselves don't have a defined relation.